# TideSDK: MySQL instead of SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, xampp, backend, tidesdk

First of all, I'm swiss, so forgive me if I mistake; My english is not so rich.

I was wondering if there is an easy(or less not so hard) way to use MySQL instead of SQLite.
The only method that I can see is to change the default backend with something like xampp, but sincerly I have no idea on how to operate in this sense.

Better not thinking about it?

Regards and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and use MySQL via TideSDKs PHP support. Just connect and talk to the MySQL Server via a PHP class.

Why don't you want to use SQLite Databases? You can use the same SQL commands on them like you do on a MySQL Server, instead that for SQLite Databases, you don't connect to a external server, but open a file. Thats the only difference.

Read more about the SQLite API, here: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Database.DB

Comment: Hi Christian! No particular reasons, I'm just new to sqlite and I had never worked without a GUI before (XAMPP has PhpMyAdmind installed for default). In other words, I was just wondering if I can work with a more familiar environment. But actually, you're right, it all has no sense. So I've found and installed sqlitemanager for Firefox and... problem solved. Thank you!